# The Loop in My Function does not change my data type (in R)

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

I intend to use a function to save me typing work for repetitive procedures. Many things are already working but not everything is working yet. Here is the code:

```
quicky <- function(df, factors){
      output <- as.character(substitute(factors)[-1])
      print(output)
      df[,output]
      for(i in names(df[,output])){
        hist(df[,as.character(i)])
        df[,as.character(i)] <- as.factor(df[,as.character(i)])#<- Why does this not work?
      }
    }

quicky(mtcars, c(cyl,hp,drat))
```

Request for help and explanation! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we are looping over the column names created from 'output', just looping over those instead of further subsetting the data and getting te `names`.  Also, in the function, `return` the dataset at the end

```
quicky <- function(df, factors){
      output <- as.character(substitute(factors)[-1])
      print(output)
     for(i in output){               
          df[[i]] <- as.factor(df[[i]])
           }

           df

    }

out <- quicky(mtcars, c(cyl,hp,drat))
str(out)
#'data.frame':  32 obs. of  11 variables:
# $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...  ###
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
# $ hp  : Factor w/ 22 levels "52","62","65",..: 11 11 6 11 15 9 20 2 7 13 ...###
# $ drat: Factor w/ 22 levels "2.76","2.93",..: 16 16 15 5 6 1 7 11 17 17 ...###
# $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
# $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
# $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
# $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
# $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

NOTE: Changed the `[` to `[[` so that it works with `data.table` and `tbl_df`

Answer (score 1):

The reason `quickly` is failing to return the results of assignments to the columns of `df` is a peculiar feature of an R `for`-loop. It returns NULL. And the last function that was evaluated within your `quicky` function was `for`. So all you need to do is add a call to the value of `df` outside of the loop:

```
quicky <- function(df, factors){
    output <- as.character(substitute(factors)[-1])
    print(output)
    df[,output]
    for(i in names(df[,output])){
        hist(df[,as.character(i)])
        df[, i] <- as.factor(df[, i ])
    }; df  # add a call to evaluate `df` 
}

str( quicky(mtcars, c(cyl,hp,drat)) )
#-------
[1] "cyl"  "hp"   "drat"
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : Factor w/ 22 levels "52","62","65",..: 11 11 6 11 15 9 20 2 7 13 ...
 $ drat: Factor w/ 22 levels "2.76","2.93",..: 16 16 15 5 6 1 7 11 17 17 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ..
```

This behavior of `for` is in contrast to most other functions in R. With a for-loop, the evaluations and assignments done within it  typically become effective outside the `for`-loop body, i.e. in the calling environment, but the function call itself returns NULL. Most other functions have no effect outside their function body environments which then requires the programmer to assign the returned value to a named object if any lasting effect is desired. (You should, of course, not expect the value of `mtcars` to be affected by that action.)